# Yeoman Directive Template Not Found

Tags: angularjs, windows, yeoman

I have an angular website that I'm developing with Yeoman.  My site works great when I'm iterating during development.  When I go to deploy the minified, uglified, versionified site after development and I got the following error while loading a directive template in the console when the site loaded.

> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/**template_name**.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

I'm using Windows 7 with the all of the yeoman web client tool set (grunt, npm, bower, compass, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error was that windows files are NOT case sensitive, and obviously javascript strings ARE.  My solution was to make sure the case of my `templateUrl` field in my directives matched exactly with the case of the file in my views folder.

Explanation:

Yeoman does this great thing where it will create an angularjs template cache for you during it's minification/uglification/versionification/deployment process in the minified javascript file.  It finds your templates referenced from your `templateUrl`s and bundles them up into plain text in a javascript file, so that you don't have to do anything and it just works!  The problem I ran into is that the template cache is indexed with the name of the file in the `templateUrl` field in my directive.

In development mode, node loads up the template from the file on the server (on my windows machine) and this load is case **insensitive**.  In the so-called "dist" mode with this template cache, this templateUrl lookup is now case **sensitive**.

My solution was to make sure the case of my `templateUrl` field matched exactly with the case of the file in my views folder.

Comment: Doesn't seem limited to Windows, I had this problem on Linux too.